# How do i refresh the sidebar menu after loading resources dynamically in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I am working on an application using react-admin, where each registered user will have it's own set of resources which are dynamically loaded, we don't know the exact resources upfront. Users register and login using Auth0. The data is fetched from Hasura. The solution is based on the following example to load the resources: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#unplugging-the-admin-using-admincontext-and-adminui

Loading the resources dynamically is working (see snippet below), however i need to refresh the page manually in order to see the resources in the sidebar menu, while the sidebar menu must be updated as soon as the dynamic resources are available. After logging out and logging back in, the resources are again not visible and a refresh is required again.

```js
    function AsyncResources() {

        ...

        return (
            <AdminUI
                title="Hasura Dashboard"
                dashboard={Dashboard}
                history={history}
                loginPage={LoginPage}
                layout={Layout}
            >
                {resources.map(resource => (
                    <Resource name={resource.name} key={resource.name} options={getOptions(resource.name)} list={getList(resource.name)} />
                ))}
                <Resource /> { /* Without this Resource, the initial page doesn't load */ }
            </AdminUI>
        );
    }
```

I had a look at the following issues regarding the same topic, but i couldn't find a definite solution to my specific problem: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5177
with answer: *"Basically you write  components for every resource but only enable what you want."* This is not a solution for me because that would mean i have to manually add every single resource of every new registered user.

I already created a custom Menu to see if that would help, but shows the same behaviour as the default Menu.

How can i make sure the dynamic loaded resources are visible in the menu without the user having to refresh the window after logging in?